# my for next loop is not working and gives error94

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Cannot understand why my *for and next loop* is not working.  What I am trying to do is to print a report for the same number of records details depending on the number value of a particular field called [nts].

If the field is empty it tells me I have *error: 94*. If the field has a value it goes to *errorhandler* mention in the program.  Can any body be so kind and help me please? Thank you in advance :)**  I am using ACCESS2007

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Report_Close()

' Delete previous data from tabMeal

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete from tabAmeal"
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()

Dim intNOM As Integer  
'NOM means number of nights meals

Dim mTimes As Integer

On Error GoTo errorhandler

intNOM = 1

mTimes = 0

mTimes = DLookup("nz([nts],0)", "tabAmeal", "[nts] > 0") 

'mTimes means number of meals

If mTimes = 0 Then

    MsgBox "File is empty GO to Query" & vbCrLf & "Error - Run the Query", vbQuestion

Else 

'now print the information found in table "tabmeal" number of times depending on the value field "nts"

    For intNOM = 1 To mTimes
    DoCmd.OpenReport "repAmeal?", acViewPreview
    Next intNOM
End If

errorhandler:

    MsgBox "Error #:- " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "LOOP not working" & vbCrLf & "Must find why this error" & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub

Private Sub Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer)

    MsgBox "Please note that you have no records to report." & vbCrLf & "You have to run the QUERY to get the required informatio."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem:
`Nz()` must be used outside of `DLookup`, not inside:

```
mTimes = Nz(DLookup("[nts]", "tabAmeal", "[nts] > 0"), 0)
```

The second problem, <s>I'm not sure. You can't open a report multiple times in `acViewPreview` (it will open only once), but it shouldn't give an error.</s>

What is the exact error message you get when nts > 0 ?

Oops. You need `Exit Sub` befor your `errorhandler:` line - the code simply enters the error handler, without there being an error. :)

Comment: OK I did all you suggested. Thank You and now the error has gone.  However the report does not report the number of times that the number in the field states.  E.g..  Client Garner has 2 nts and Ransley has three nts so the report should print : Garner - Garner - Ransley - Ransley - Ransley